# How to pass a specific prop when the props can have multiple types in React, Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-props

Props Interface with data of different types:

```
interface ResultProp {
    type: string
    data: {} | AProp | BProp | CProp | DProp
}
```

Cardview will pass props data to respective component based on the props.type:

```
const Cardview:React.FC<ResultProp> = (props) => {
    const renderComponent = () => {
        switch(props.type){
            case "aprop":
                return <A {...props.data} />    // Type mismatch here
            // rest of the types ...
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className="cardview">
            {() => renderComponent}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Component receiving props from Cardview:

```
const A: React.FC<AProp> = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for TypeScript to understand the relationship between `props.type` and `props.data`, you need to use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions):

```
type ResultProp = {type: "aprop", data: AProp} | {type: "bprop", data: BProp} | ...;
```